# Loading a laravel view with .html extension

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to have Laravel load view templates with a .html extension?

I'm rebuilding an existing app that has a bunch of .html files that are uploaded by users. It's a sort of multi-tenant application where each user can control the look and feel of their area by uploading templates.

I need to rebuild the app and make the change completely transparent to the users so I'd like to keep the .html extensions.

Answer (score 7):

The best way I have found is to use View::addExtension in your base controller;

Here's my code sample:

View::addExtension('blade.html','blade');

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupLayout()
    {

        // Allows us to use easy-to-edit html extension files.
        // You can set 2nd param to 'php' is you want to 
        // just process with php (no blade tags)
        View::addExtension('blade.html','blade');


        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `BaseController` is no more in from laravel 5.0 onwards

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2023 - Laravel 10**

Laravel 10 knows file types in folder `resources/views`:

```php
    protected $extensions = [
        'blade.php' => 'blade',
        'php' => 'php',
        'css' => 'file',
        'html' => 'file',
    ];
```

as you can see in `Illuminate\View\Factory`.

Answer (score -3):

I am afraid Blade engine loads `.php` and `.blade.php` files only.

From your description I assume the view files are static, since they are HTML only. 
If so, rename them to `.php` after user uploads view files - should not bring performance impact to your application, since  there is nothing to process anyway.

Comment: I think I've found a solution, but I've run into another roadblock (That's for another day).

The solution is View::addExtension('html', 'php')

Which will cause laravel to load html files and run them through php.

Comment: @Mcg1978 where do I've to add `View::addExtension('html', 'php')`