# Laravel Loadview not loading file

Tags: laravel, pdf, dompdf, downloadfileasync, laravel-dompdf

when I try to load my file it loads only file URL what is the solution
I try this but it loads only file path in pdf file

```
return PDF::loadFile(public_path().'/your_html.html')->stream('download.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file is in HTML format and also your path indicates it's outside the resources folder, you have to add your HTML file in blade format in `resources` folder.

`loadView` function first render the view and then pass it to `loadHTML` function.

DomPDF https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/blob/00443b33aff68f9e996de536c8f62735c4042131/src/PDF.php

```
    public function loadView(string $view, array $data = [], array $mergeData = [], ?string $encoding = null): self
    {
        $html = $this->view->make($view, $data, $mergeData)->render();
        return $this->loadHTML($html, $encoding);
    }
```

And if you want to load `html` file not in `blade` format from `resource` folder so you can checkout how to include html extension file.

[Laravel Blade @include .html files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377352/laravel-blade-include-html-files)